# "sudo apt-get upgrade" not working

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a Dell Vostro 15 3000 series laptop.
when I hit

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it works fine and then I hit

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it shows me:
[image]

and then when i press `Y` it gives me errors as below:

```
(Reading database ... 204809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace postgresql-9.1 9.1.16-0ubuntu0.12.04 (using .../postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb) ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of postgresql-9.1, which would be broken by installation of postgresql-client-9.1 ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure postgresql-9.1 (broken by postgresql-client-9.1).
Preparing to replace postgresql-client-9.1 9.1.16-0ubuntu0.12.04 (using .../postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb) ...
De-configuring postgresql-9.1 ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
vgo@vgo-dell:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,282 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 204809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace postgresql-9.1 9.1.16-0ubuntu0.12.04 (using .../postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb) ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of postgresql-9.1, which would be broken by installation of postgresql-client-9.1 ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure postgresql-9.1 (broken by postgresql-client-9.1).
Preparing to replace postgresql-client-9.1 9.1.16-0ubuntu0.12.04 (using .../postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb) ...
De-configuring postgresql-9.1 ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                              * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 246.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now what can I do to solve this problem and upgrade?

Comment: Try: "sudo apt-get -f install".

Comment: just hit this command ? `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve your problem by running:

```
 sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql*.prerm
```

Add

```
exit 0
```

directly after

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
```

so the the new file would be like:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

exit 0

VERSION=9.1



. /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions

stop_version $VERSION

if [ "$1" = remove ]; then
    remove_version $VERSION
fi
```

Now run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should works

Comment: actually what should be try to do using this steps ?

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: actually with this `exit 0 `  what are you doing  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24709/discussion-between-virbhadrasinh-and-maythux).

Comment: Exit 0 just ends the script and returns "No errors". Actually it's tricking the packet manager to think that "everything" is fine. If you take a close look you can see that somehow shutting down the postgresql db brings back an error.

invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This exit 0, won't do anything else but tell that the value is 0 or "no error"!